# searchin value according to custom field in liferay

Tags: liferay

i have create one custom field in calender i want to search event whic meets custom field criteria  how it can be possible because there is no method which in service class

Answer (score 0):

Custom attributes are stored in the Expando* tables in Liferay and depending on how you define the custom fields it can also provide indexing and searching for you. It's a bit hard to say more without knowing more, I guess.